# Activating URL from Another Page URL Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Hi everybody and thanks for reading,

Basically, what I'm trying to do is activate a URL (which has a resulting jQuery plugin effect) from clicking a URL on a different page. As it stands, it does nothing other than link to the actual anchor tag without any effect. Weirdly though, if I refresh the page by pressing F5, this DOES activate the anchor tag with the proper effect.

Some information:

- jQuery installation v1.5
- jQuery plugin quicksand v1.2.1

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
        $(window.location.hash).click();  
    }
});
```

HTML (initiating hyperlink with ID of 'ext'):

```
<li><a href="gallery.html" class="selected">Gallery</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="gallery.html#ext">Exterior</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kitchen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lounge</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bedroom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bathroom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hall</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scenery</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

HTML (targeted hyperlink with ID of 'ext'):

```
<ul class="gallerynav">
   <li class="selected-1"><a href="#" data-value="all">All<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a id="ext" href="#" data-value="exterior">Exterior<span></span></a></li></a>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="kitchen">Kitchen<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="lounge">Lounge<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="bedroom">Bedroom<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="bathroom">Bathroom<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="hall">Hall<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="scenery">Scenery<span></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-value="misc">Misc<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.